# Changing the username color to be white

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, master-page, css, custom-masterpage

I have a SharePoint web application which contains both a team site & a community site. I have changed the upper left suite bar colour to be blue,  but this will make the username not very readable. So is there a way to modify the username text color to be white instead of black?
Below is a picture for the username CSS using IE developer tool:-

[image]

Thanks

Comment: ... how did you do the current customisation? Just add in another CSS statement to colour the required text white.

Comment: thanks for the reply. currently i did my customization by adding a cusotm CSS file insdie my StyleLibrary folder. but for the user name i can not determine the Div id which is responsible for displaying the username , as seems it will be created by javaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS class:

`div#welcomeMenuBox span.ms-core-menu-root { color: white; }`

Comment: thanks for the reply, i added this to my custom CSS, but it did not change the color.

Comment: Does it have any effect if you add ´!important´, for testing purpose only? Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3706876/286244

Comment: Here is my current custom CSS 
"div#welcomeMenuBox span.ms-core-menu-root { color: white !important; }". But this did not have any effect.